# Cannot instantiate class packageName.pageName

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am getting "Cannot instantiate class packageName.pageName" will trying to execute the test cases in selenium. I tried a lot but didn't find the the place where i am doing the mistake.

Below is my Login page

```
package detailsPkg_user;

public class Login {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    String username = "userName";
    String password = "passWord";
    String baseurl = "http://mybusiness.com/login.aspx";
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // 10 seconds


public class Details {  
    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void loginpage() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\From H\\Selenium Package\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--test-type");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","D:\\From H\\Selenium Package\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseurl);


        WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("UserName")));
        username.sendKeys(userName);

        WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("PassWord")));
        password.sendKeys(passWord);

        WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ButtonClick")));
        button.click();

    }

    // Selecting a date from date picker
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void RecordSearch() {
        WebElement calendar = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("CalendarId")));
        calendar.click();


        WebElement month = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        month.click();


        WebElement day = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        day.click();


        WebElement submit = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Submit")));
        submit.click();


    }

        driver.close();
}
```

And Below is the detailSearch page code

```
 package detailsPkg_user;


import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;



public class detailSearch extends Login {

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void loginpageDetail() { 

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\From H\\Selenium Package\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--test-type");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","D:\\From H\\Selenium Package\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseurl);



        WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("UserName")));
        username.sendKeys(userName);

        WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Password")));
        password.sendKeys(passWord);

        WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ButtonClick")));
        button.click();
    }   

    // Selecting and clicking DetailSearch menu
    @Test(priority = 3) 
    public void detailSelect() {    
        WebElement detailMenu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        detailMenu.click();



        // Datepicker of "From" calendar
        WebElement datepickerFrom = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("calendarId01")));
        datepickerFrom.click();


        WebElement monthPreviousFrom = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("leftarrow_calendar_NP']/img")));
        monthPreviousFrom.click();


        WebElement dayFirst = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        dayFirst.click();


        // Datepicker of "To" calendar
        WebElement datepickerTo = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("calendarId02")));
        datepickerTo.click();


        WebElement monthPreviousTo = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("leftarrow_calendar_NP']/img")));
        monthPreviousTo.click();


        WebElement monthLast = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        monthLast.click();

    }

        // Click "Submit"
        WebElement submit = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_contentMiddle_btnSearch")));
        submit.click();


        WebElement logout = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        logout.click();

        driver.close();
    }

}
```

When i am trying to execute the project. I am getting the following error in the console.

```
    org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class detailsPkg_user.detailSearch
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:382)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:295)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:118)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:183)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:416)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:242)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:212)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:166)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_7$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_7.java:26)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_7$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_7.java:59)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:161)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1290)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1277)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1131)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at detailsPkg_user.Login.<init>(Login.java:25)
    at detailsPkg_user.detailSearch.<init>(CDRSearch.java:21)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: What's line 25 of `Login.java`?

Comment: @chiastic-security...It's a blank line. Just the next line to "WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // 10 seconds"

Comment: Does that mean there's some code missing as that doesn't look like line 25?

Comment: @JeffC...The above is the issue which i mentioned you.

Comment: @Josh...i don't think any code were missing...

Comment: Something is missing because this code will not compile and I've only tried the Login class. I'm getting several errors. You have `username` and `password` defined twice. `driver.close()` is out in the middle of no where. Take some time and make the fixes that Priyanshu suggested and then repost the complete and cleaned up code if you still have issues. Including any updated error messages.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have instantiated driver in a method. Try to instantiate it out of method, you may use `@BeforeSuite` for that.

Also there is a problem with this line `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);`. Here you have created wait instance with a null driver as the driver is getting instantiated later.

I am not sure, why people write so complex code. You could have achieved same without making it that much complex.This would solve your issue:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

public class DetailSearch extends Login {

    @BeforeSuite
    public void instantiateDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\From H\\Selenium Package\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--test-type");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","D:\\From H\\Selenium Package\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseurl);
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void loginpageDetail() { 



        WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("UserName")));
        username.sendKeys("userName");

        WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Password")));
        password.sendKeys("passWord");

        WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ButtonClick")));
        button.click();
    }   

    // Selecting and clicking DetailSearch menu
    @Test(priority = 3) 
    public void detailSelect() {    
        WebElement detailMenu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        detailMenu.click();



        // Datepicker of "From" calendar
        WebElement datepickerFrom = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("calendarId01")));
        datepickerFrom.click();


        WebElement monthPreviousFrom = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("leftarrow_calendar_NP']/img")));
        monthPreviousFrom.click();


        WebElement dayFirst = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        dayFirst.click();


        // Datepicker of "To" calendar
        WebElement datepickerTo = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("calendarId02")));
        datepickerTo.click();


        WebElement monthPreviousTo = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("leftarrow_calendar_NP']/img")));
        monthPreviousTo.click();


        WebElement monthLast = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        monthLast.click();

    }

        // Click "Submit"
        WebElement submit = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_contentMiddle_btnSearch")));



        WebElement logout = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
    }


import java.util.Arrays;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    String username = "userName";
    String password = "passWord";
    String baseurl = "http://mybusiness.com/login.aspx";
    WebDriverWait wait;


public class Details {  
    @BeforeSuite
    public void instantiateDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\From H\\Selenium Package\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--test-type");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","D:\\From H\\Selenium Package\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // 10 seconds
    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void loginpage() {
        driver.get(baseurl);


        WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("UserName")));
        username.sendKeys("userName");

        WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("PassWord")));
        password.sendKeys("passWord");

        WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ButtonClick")));
        button.click();

    }

    // Selecting a date from date picker
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void RecordSearch() {
        WebElement calendar = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("CalendarId")));
        calendar.click();


        WebElement month = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        month.click();


        WebElement day = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPath")));
        day.click();


        WebElement submit = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Submit")));
        submit.click();


    }

}
}
```

Comment: I have removed few of the methods, as I was getting some errors.

Comment: ...I tried with your solution and even some from mine. But it's not working. It's opening 3 browsers instances but not entering username and password.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the beginning of your code and step through it noting where the 3 different browser instances are launched and fix/remove them.

Answer (score 0):

PLease check whether the folder structure where you kept driver files / JRE files have changed or not . Even the small change in folder name can also be a reason for this issue . 
If changed -update that path as environmental variable .

Comment: that not the issue. The issue was in logic of progamming